# Error when building Netbeans 11.0 from source

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, build.xml, windows-10-desktop

I installed Apache Ant version 1.10.5 on my Windows 10 desktop system in order to build Netbeans 11.0 from source. I set the environmental variables and ant seems to be running properly. However, when I cd to the Netbeans folder and run ant to build it, I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
E:\Netbeans 11.0\nbbuild\build.xml:514: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Netbeans 11.0\nbbuild\build.xml:509: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Netbeans 11.0\nbbuild\build.xml:556: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\Netbeans 11.0\nb\updatecenters\build.xml:44: exec returned: 1
```

Does anyone have any idea what would be causing this or where I could look up what the possible causes of "exec returned: 1" could be? Also, I am using jdk1.8.0_212.

Here is the surrounding code for the build.xml file:

```
39  <target name="bootstrap" description="Bootstrap NetBeans-specific Ant extensions."
40          depends="-jdk-init,-load-build-properties">
41    <fail message="You need to run on JDK 8+ to build NetBeans; java.home=${java.home}">
42        <condition>
43            <matches pattern="^1\.[01234567].*" string="${java.version}"/>
44        </condition>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at line 44 in E:\Netbeans 11.0\nb\updatecenters\build.xml ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how exactly to read it. I posted that line and some context above in my most recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should have JDK 8+

Second you need good internet speed.

or i can Say a very simple solution for you all
Just go netbeans https://netbeans.apache.org/
       don't go for source file

download bin.zip file
after extracting the zip folder paste in `c:\ Drive`
and open the netbeans folder you will
`C:\netbeans\bin`

in this you find 2 exe file 
**netbeans.exe** 
**netbeans64.exe**

run as per your system is 64bit or 32bit

Comment: He's asking about building from source, this answer is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

In my case that was a folder create permission issue . So, on windows I ran command prompt **as administrator**. Have ran

```
ant
```

Then this error disappeared